# get the inner button of asp.net grid cell and change its css property using c sharp?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

i have a grid but when i hide its cell using

```
    GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].CssClass = "controlview";
```

and css class

```
  .controlview{
  visibilty = hidden;
}
```

it also hide the border of cell but i want to hide only button inside cell whose name is button using c sharp how to acess inside tr a td name input button

```
  GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].CssClass = "controlview";
```

so that my grid cell border color donot vanish only button hide it self

Answer (score 0):

```
((Button)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].FindControl("<Button ID>")).Attributes["class"] = "controlview";
```

**OR**

```
((Button)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].FindControl("<Button ID>")).Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
```

**OR**

```
((Button)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].FindControl("<Button ID>")).CssClass = "controlview";
```

**OR**

```
((Button)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].FindControl("<Button ID>")).Attributes.Add("style","visibility:hidden");
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. quick watch window shows value = null

Comment: it is ASP.net control so what should i do to acess control instead of "<Button ID>")

Comment: problem is button id only how to acess it

Comment: don't paste it as it is, rather use your button id there

Comment: What's Id of your asp.net button?